# How to remove whitespace from XElement object created from XElement.ReadFrom(XmlReader)

Tags: whitespace, xmlreader, xelement

I am parsing a large xml file. So I am using an XmlReader in combination with XElement instead of XElement.Load().

I have created as XElement object from XmlReader as shown below and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx).

```
static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamRootChildDoc(string uri)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri, xmlReaderSettings))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (reader.Name == "Child")
                    {
                        XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                        if (el != null)
                            yield return el;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save this XElement object content in the database as string without the whitespace. None of the below 3 ways work. Just a note, if I load the xml in memory using XElement.Load(), the ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) works.

```
<root>  <child></child>  </root> //xml saved in db with whitespace
<root><child></child></root> //want to save as this

XElement.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) //
XElement.ToString(SaveOptions.None)
XElement.ToString()
```

The XmlReaderSettings I am using for the XmlReader object are below. I tried IgnoreWhitespace =true/false with no luck but I cannot set it as true as some elements are skipped (for reason for skipping, see [Why does XmlReader skip every other element if there is no whitespace separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2299632/58678)).

```
    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
    //xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;//cannot use this setting
```

It works if I parse the XElement object but that defeats the whole purpose of using XmlReader as XElement.Parse() loads the xml in memory.

```
XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
XElement.Parse(el.ToString(), LoadOptions.None)
```

How can I remove the whitespace?

**Edit: This is what I had to do:**

1. The elements skipping is due to two reads `reader.Read()` and `XElement.ReadFrom(reader)` in the same iteration thereby skipping every other element. Fixing the loop mentioned in the link above solves that. The issue has nothing to do with `XmlReaderSettings`.
2. `xelement.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)` removes the pretty formatting.

Comment: I would think that XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace is the way to go. What xml element are skipped when you use this setting?

Comment: I tried with IgnoreWhitespace as true and false but I still get whitespace. I meant, with IgnoreWhitespace=true, some nodes are skipped i.e. instead of getting back 200 child nodes I get back only 100 - I did not look much into this. With IgnoreWhitespace=false I get back all 200 nodes. 

Since it worked with XElement.Load(), it has to do with XmlReader during the XmlReader.Create() call and IgnoreWhitespace was the first thing I tried. Wondering if there is another setting that I need to set for the reader.

Comment: Anybody? I just ran into the same problem...

Comment: @TheChairman, did not find a solution. i ended doing what i mentioned in the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does XmlReader skip every other element if there is no whitespace separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299632/why-does-xmlreader-skip-every-other-element-if-there-is-no-whitespace-separator)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.whitespacehandling.aspx) form the XMLTextReader class. The XMLTextReader has a method "WhitespaceHandling", which you can set to none. It would be helpfull to answer this question, if you could have provided a test XML file, to test is XMLTextReader works.