# Why does XmlReader skip every other element if there is no whitespace separator?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, whitespace

I'm seeing strange behavior when I try to parse XML using the LINQ XmlReader class.  Test case below: it looks like whether I use `(XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader)` or one of the `Read()` methods on XmlReader, it misses the second `bar` elements in the input XML.  If any whitespace is added between the `</bar>` and `<bar>` then it will parse the second `bar` element correctly.

Does anyone have an idea of why the input stream gets messed up and how to get around this problem?

```
    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void ShouldParseCorrectNumberOfElements()
    {
        var xml = @"<foo><bar>wtf</bar><bar>wtf2</bar></foo>";
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));

        int count = 0;
        xmlReader.MoveToContent();
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "bar")
            {
                var element = xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();
                Console.WriteLine("just got an " + element);
                count++;
            }
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(2, count);
    }
```

Comment: The loop can be significantly optimized by using `ReadToFollowing("bar")` instead of `Read()` (works with Jon's answer too).

Comment: I have a similar case and i'm using `ReadToFollowing` with `While` and `ReadOuterXml` inside the while loop. If the document is formatted with newlines it is functioning properly. When I have a single line document it skips all of the following nodes.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're calling `ReadOuterXml`, which will consume the element and place the "cursor" just before the next element. You're then calling `Read` again, which moves the cursor on (e.g. to the text node within the element).

Here's an alternative to your loop:

```
while (!xmlReader.EOF)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.NodeType);
    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "bar")
    {
        var element = xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();
        Console.WriteLine("just got an " + element);
        count++;                
    }
    else
    {
        xmlReader.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that "off by one" feeling... Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Are you perhaps skipping a line by calling the Read() function within the while loop condition and then the ReadOuterXml() function within the loop itself?