# 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType error when parsing XML file

Tags: vb.net, xmlreader

I'm very new to XML parsing and don't really know what I'm doing. I'm trying to parse a file in XML, but have encountered this error:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: ''Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType.'
```

Here's the code below:

```
    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
    Dim xmlR = XmlReader.Create(jmdictpath, settings)

    Do While xmlR.Read()
        If Not xmlR.IsEmptyElement And xmlR.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
            MsgBox(xmlR.ReadElementContentAsString)
        End If
    Loop
```

The error runs on the line `MsgBox(xmlR.ReadElementContentAsString)`. I've tested that the element is not empty, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Then I checked the xmlReader object in QuickWatch, and it looks like what the object is currently trying to read is a whitespace or line return character:

[image]

Is there some standard method to handle all cases like this when parsing XML so that whitespace characters don't get picked up as XML tags and confuse the reader?

Comment: Have a look at your `Not` with your `And`.  Are you sure it is evaluating like ((Not first) and second) vs (not(first and second))?  Try adding some parens and let us know if it behaves differently.

Comment: I think you might be having issues similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399850/c-sharp-whitespaces-issue-with-xmlreader) Try setting the IgnoreWhitespace property to true on XmlReaderSettings

Comment: @jazakari That seemed to fix the problem, thanks :). I now have a different problem but it's for a different question and some more research on how XML parsing works I guess haha